# Prevent getting a generator object

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

Considering the following function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def duplicate_checker(word_list):
    word_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for i,item in enumerate(tweet_list):
        word_dict[item].append(i)

    return ((key, locs)  for key, locs in word_dict.items() if len(locs) >= 1)
```

When I call the function with a list of words, it should check for duplicates and return a dictionary that contains the words in the list as keys, and as value a list of their positions in the list of words that was used as an argument to call the function.

However when I want to print the results it returns this:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02E306C0>
```

How can I make it return the dict as I described above?

Comment: Either add a `dict` call or make it a dictionary comprehension (`{key: locs for key, locs ...}`). Currently, the generator is *exactly what you're asking for*.

Comment: What is `word_dict = defaultdict(list)`? Is `defaultdict()` a custom function?

Comment: [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

Comment: @KevinGuan presumably `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, forgot that :P

Comment: @KevinGuan yes sorry, I forgot to add the 'from collections import defaultdict'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `return dict(...)` or `return {key: locs for ...}`

The second version should be more pythonic and preferred for python 2.7 or 3.1+

Comment: Thank you for your help. The second suggestion was what I was looking for.